# Ruby on rails install guide for ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, web-applications, web-deployment

need your help about which site to use to get **good** content on **installing** and deploying *guides* for ***rails*** app. And also it could bi video. But i need good öne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many good resources if you simply google `rails` and your OS of choice.

Here are some I personally find good for Ubuntu:

- [Digital Ocean's Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [RailsApps Guide](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html)
- [Chris Oliver's Guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04)